# Observable.generator with state, where the new state is updated asynchronously

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

This is a slightly contrived example, but bear with me.  Let's say I have a method such as:

```
Single<String> getValue(int offset);
```

I want to call this a bunch of times, passing a different offset each time, but where the offset is based on the number of characters previously returned.

So maybe `getValue(0)` returns "Cat".  Then because it returned 3 characters, I want to call `getValue(3)`, which might return "Horse".  Then tallying up the number of characters returned, my next call would be `getValue(8)`.

`Observable.generate(initialState, generator)` where the state is the offset doesn't seem to give me what I want here, because it requires that my generator returns the next state, which I don't necessarily know.

How would I go about creating an Observable that generates the values as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interested to see if there are any less verbose solutions, but here's what I'm running with for now:

I've defined a "State" class that holds the offset, and delegates to the real implementation.  This takes advantage of the fact that `generate` is synchronous.

```
private static class State {
    private final int offset = 0;
    private final AnimalFetcher delegate;
    State(AnimalFetcher delegate) { this.delegate = delegate; }

    void getNextValue(Emitter<String> emitter) {
        delegate.getValue(offset)
            .doOnSuccess(animal -> offset += animal.size())
            .subscribe(emitter::onNext, emitter::onError);
    }
}

Observable<String> getAllTheAnimals() {
    return Observable.generate(
        () -> new State(this),
        State::getNextValue
    );
}
```